# Вращение круга коряво отображается

Tags: css

Если навести на круг курсор и сделать в браузере масштаб 80%, то круг при вращении не ровный.

```css
span{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px dotted red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
span:hover{
  animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes spin {
 100% {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}
```

```html
<span></span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xcpLemot/

как это можно исправить? т.е. чтобы при вращении круг был ровный
В хроме масштаб выбирается кликнув в верхнем правом углу на точки.

Comment: интересно, если сделать ширину границы один пиксель - все ок

Comment: если не убирая hover уменьшить до 75, а потом вернуть на 80, то тоже все ок. Но вообще, я не вижу смысла в решении этой "проблемы", да и не уверен, что решение есть.

Comment: Баг это, возникает только при масштабировании, так что смысла фиксить то и нет. Оно(масштабирование) всегда как-то странно работает.

Comment: ок, благодарю, мне нужно было ваше мнение на счет этого бага

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно сделать так:

```css
div{
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-flex;
}
span{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px dotted red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
div:hover{
  animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes spin {
 100% {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}
```

```html
<div><span></span></div>
```